# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on "Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen…"

Tags: 16.04, boot

When I boot my Ubuntu 16.04 system, the screen shows:

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 914558/6250496 files, 10712202/24999680 blocks
...
[OK] Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
     Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
```

Detailed information is [here](http://i1.bvimg.com/643952/c6227606069e32f9.jpg).

How to fix it? Can anyone give some advice?

Comment: The image link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

startup from live cd.

enter to `sudo` mode

```
mount your /dev/sdaX to /mnt
mount /{dev proc sys} to /mnt/{dev proc sys}
mount /dev/sd1 (boot part) to /mnt/boot
chroot /mnt
vi /mnt/etc/default/grub
```

mark with `#` param `DEFAULT_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`

save it

```
grub-update
```

init 6 ( boot from your hard)

on grub menu press <kbd>E</kbd>

find 'splash quiet' and remove them
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> - to continue load system

after search in google man for fix this trouble (how to set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` for your config)